# What is the black rectangular shape in "In My Feelings (Kiki Do You Love Me)" video clip?

Tags: meaning, music-video

I just noticed something weird in the *In My Feelings* video clip:

[image]
<sub><sup>(Screenshot from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRS_PpOrUZ4))</sup></sub>

There is a black rectangle in the middle left part of the screen, that appears at random intervals throughout the clip.

What is this rectangle? Does it mean anything? I don't remember seeing something like that in any other video clip I've ever seen.